# Masking colors using opencv

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, masking

I tried to mask image by its color using opencv.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

After importing libraries, I load the image

```
img = cv2.imread('gmaps.jpg')
image = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
plt.imshow(image);
```

Turn the color into hsv

```
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
plt.imshow(hsv);
```

Masking process

```
low_orange = np.array([44, 6, 100])
high_orange = np.array([44, 24, 99])
masking = cv2.inRange(hsv,low_orange, high_orange)
plt.imshow(masking);
```

The result isn't what I expected.

**Image   :**
[image: Real image]

**Result :**
[image: Result]

**EDIT:** I want to mask the building only. Instead I got the result of masking all of the frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using my answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69295962/drawing-bbox-for-realtime-object-detection-without-ml/69307887#69307887) I manage to extract the right values for you

[image]

Code:

```
    frame = cv2.imread("Xv6gx.png")
    blurred_frame = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame, (5, 5), 0)
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(blurred_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    lower = np.array([4, 0, 7])
    upper = np.array([87, 240, 255])
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

    for contour in contours:
        area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
        if area > 5000:
             # -- Draw Option 1 --
             cv2.drawContours(frame, contour, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)

             # -- Draw Option 2--
             # rect = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
             # x, y, w, h = rect
             # cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    cv2.imshow("Mask", mask)
    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)

    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Final Results:

[image]

Comment: How did you get the correct number for lower and upper orange colors?

Comment: @zzzz In the beginning of my answer I hyperlink other answer of mine to find the colors. btw if you are pleased with my answer, can you upvote and verify (v symbol left to my answer) my answer?

Comment: @RoyAmoial you can also try LAB colour space

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't expect the low **Value** (100) to exceed the high **Value** (99).

Also, **OpenCV** uses a range of 0..180 for **Hue** rather than 0..360, so you likely need to divide your 44 by 2.